# Why does adding a String and an int act this way?

Tags: java

When I run the following code:

```
public class LianXi1 
{ 
   public static void main(String args[]) 
   { 
     int a=12; 
     int b=23; 
     System.out.println("case 1"+a); //

     System.out.println("case 2"+b); //

   } 
}
```

I get this result:

```
@ubuntu:~/mycode/test$ java LianXi1 
case 112
case 223
```

But I don't understand the result, who can help?

Comment: What are your doubts exactly? What did you expect?

Comment: If you want to perform addition you would use `String.valueOf(1+12)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you add a string and an integer together, it performs "String concatenation", where it's converting your integer into a string and sticking it on the end of the other string.

```
"Case 1" + 12
```

... is the same as

```
"Case 1" + "12"
```

So your result will be the first string with the characters `12` stuck on after it.

Thus:  `Case 112`

From the Java documentation on Strings:

> "The Java language provides special support for the string
>   concatenation operator ( + ), and for conversion of other objects to
>   strings. String concatenation is implemented through the StringBuffer
>   class and its append method. String conversions are implemented
>   through the method toString, defined by Object and inherited by all
>   classes in Java. For additional information on string concatenation
>   and conversion, see Gosling, Joy, and Steele, The Java Language
>   Specification."

But be careful!  Adding works left to right, so what would the follwing print?

```
System.out.println(1 + 2 + "test" + 3 + 4);
```

First, it does `1 + 2`, which is equal to `3`.

Then it does `3` (the result of the last step) `+ "test"`, which causes `"3test"`

Next, it does `"3test" + 3`, which results in `"3test3"`.

And finally, `"3test3 + 4` is `"3test34`.

As you can see, its a good idea to put parentheses around things to ensure they come out in the order you want.

`(1 + 2) + "test" + (3 + 4)` would be "3test7" because the math in the parentheses has precedence.

Comment: Thank you very much for so detailed explaination! And it really helps a lot!

Answer (score 2):

When a concatenation operation is performed between a string and an int, or a string an any other primitive data type (like float, long, short, etc) the primitive is always converted to a string to be appended on the original string.  Your output is displaying the string plus the string representation of the variables a and b.

See: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=217

Answer (score 1):

if you use '+' operator implict function call like "toString()"

change your type int => Integer then try this.

```
public class Main { 
   public static void main(String args[]) { 
     Integer a=12; 
     Integer b=23;

     System.out.println("case 1" + a.toString()); //
     System.out.println("case 2" + b.toString()); //
   } 
}
```

because

```
"case 1" + a => "case 1" + a.toString(); => "case 1" + "12";
```

like other type too same

```
 this + a => this.toString() + a.toString()
```

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean to "add" a String and an int? In Java, you *must* have the same type on both sides of an operator to perform the desired action. In many cases when there is a mismatch, Java will convert one value to the same type as the other. In this case, the int is converted to a String because it would be difficult in general to convert a String to an int. Now the + operator "concatenates" the two Strings "case 1" and "12" in the first println() call. "Concatenate" simply means to join the two Strings into a single String, which in this case creates the String "case112" which you see output.

Answer (score 0):

it is default in java. if you do "string" + "int", java will first convert the integer to a string and then concatenate the string and the "int" string. 
So in your case:
"Case 1" is concatenated with the string value of int "12", the result is "Case 112". The same is "Case 223". 
If you would like to make it do the addition operation. you should do like this
System.out.println("case " + (1+a) );
then the output would be: 
case 13

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to read the [The Java Language Specification#15.18.1 String Concatenation Operator +](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.18.1)

Answer (score -2):

When you print a integer, besides a string, it just acts like a string. However, if you did:

```
System.out.println(1+1);
```

It would print out 2. This is because the integer is next to another.

If you did:

```
System.out.println("Test"+1+1);
```

It would print Test2. Because, you look at the addition of numbers first. Hope I helped.

Comment: No, `System.out.println("Test" + 1 + 1);` would print `"Test11`. Try it.